# phpmyadmin on apache2 reload: Unknown Authz provider: valid-user error

Tags: apache-2.4, phpmyadmin

After standard installation of phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 14.04 I found `<site>/phpmyadmin` doesn't work. After googling it, I found this can be solved with adding this line

```
Include "/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/*.conf"
```

Added to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` config file.

But after apache reload I get this error message

```
 * Reloading web server apache2
 * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 30 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:
Unknown Authz provider: valid-user
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

How can I fix error and make `phpmyadmin` working?

Comment: What's "standard installation" mean here -- did you use the packaged (dpkg/apt/aptitude/etc) version or download the source from phpMyAdmin and uncompress it to your web root?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the module 'mod_authz_user' is not enabled. You can use `a2enmod` to enable it for your apache installation.

```
sudo a2enmod authz_user
```

It will now tell you that is has been activated and that you need to restart your apache instance. In Ubuntu 14.04 this can be done as follows:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem ... after replacing a failed harddisk in mdraid and restarting the server in that process Apache failed to start with the same error message:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 30 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:
Unknown Authz provider: valid-user
```

But the module `authz_user` was already loaded. As it turned out the problem was something completely different.

Running `sudo apache2ctl -M` showed a different error:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/net.example.ghost.conf:
Invalid command '<Proxy', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action '-M' failed.
```

I had to enable a couple of modules and run `sudo apache2ctl -M` again until all necessary modules were loaded. After that, Apache started without problems, and without any changes in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Problem. What fixed it was putting a "-" between valid and user, like that: valid-user.

Answer (score -2):

You need to edit phpmyadmin config file `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` and remove line (30 in my case) `Authz provider: valid-user`. Save it. Apache should now reload normally, and `phpmyadmin` should work now.

Comment: You just removed the requirement that a user be verified before accessing whatever... just FWIW.

Answer (score -3):

I put V capitalized in valid-user in my case. I recommend you check If you have the same case .

the route is /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess

Comment: It is unlikely that editing an htaccess file will resolve an error in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` ....